# Entry won't update

Tags: channel, entries, updating

I'm at a loss on this one. I have an entry in my products channel. The status is wide. The entry is showing up on the home page. OK, great.

But now I want to change some text on the entry. I make the change and hit submit. It stays on the form, rather than going to the summary of the entry with the 4 or 5 links at the bottom. And the change doesn't seem to take, because the front end stays the same as before. Plus, when I get out of the update form on the back end, then go back in, the change has disappeared.

I am able to add a new entry. I'm also able to make changes to that entry. But the existing entry won't change.

This is a site I've cloned from another site. The data is from that other site, but it's in a new database, on a new server (cloud). I have followed all instructions for moving sites between servers.

Any help would be much appreciated. (BTW, we're using version 2.5.5.)

Comment: check if all required fields are correctly selected!. Check your gmail =)

Comment: I've had similar ghost stuff happen and without problem solving just recreate entry. Its almost a corruption somewhere and CBF finding it.

Comment: Can you see under "Options" tab and make sure that correct author is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd double check that the new database credentials have been added to the database.php file and that they are correct for the new host. [Deeploy helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) can often be useful when moving to a new environment to make sure all the settings are correct for it's new location.

Failing that then have a good check that there aren't in fact any errors on the Publish screen or notifications bar at the top. These can be very subtle and can often be missed resulting in the symptoms that you describe. I've certainly had this before when clients have described the exact same thing only to find that it was due to a subtle error message that wasn't noticed. If that's the case then [Mega Error](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ep-mega-error) may help to make them a little...less subtle.. :)

Comment: The second proposed issue was exactly it, @Ian. Also, thanks for the links to the very useful looking plugins.